# laravel api not authenticating bearer token

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8

I have developed laravel api using laravel 8 and using passport.
I generate token and when I try to access using that token it send me to Middleware/authenticate.php redirectTo() function.

After some time when I try to generate again new token it send me to same redirectTo method even though that route is not in auth:api middleware group.

Even route without any middleware also go for auth and send it to redirectTo method.

routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function(){
  Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class,'login']);
  Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class,'register']);
});
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth:api'],'prefix' => 'v1'], function(){
  Route::get('/contacts',[ContactController::class,'index']);
  Route::get('/contacts/{id}',[ContactController::class,'show']);
});
Route::get('/greeting', function () {
   return 'Hello World 2';
});
```

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Http/kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'auth:api',
    ],
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'is_admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
];
```

Even simple "/greeting" route also get authenticated and send to redirectTo method.
So non of route is working properly

Comment: are those routes declared in `web.php` ?

Comment: no all are declared in routes/api.php

Comment: do you have another route with variable declaration exp: `Route::get('/{variable}', ... );`

Comment: No I don't have any such     Route::get('/{variable}', ... ); route